# WP displays "some_strange_number Version" in the bottom right corner

Tags: errors

I didn't know what's wrong with my Wordpress. All looks fine the last time I logged yesterday.

In the bottom right corner displays "`Version some_strange_number`" and when I'm trying to install a new plugin in the search page `/wp-admin/plugin-install.php` all plugin displays a message `Incompatible with your version of WordPress`. But i'm using Wordpress latest version

Screenshot:
[image: Incompatible with your version of WordPress]

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean *literally* `some_strange_number`?

The version of WP install is captured in global `$wp_version` variable, defined in  `wp-includes/version.php`. Unfortunately since it's not a *constant* it can be modified in runtime.

Check the file for being modified/corrupted, if it's fine then some other code interferes with it.